# Formatting Schema with NextJS

Tags: reactjs, next.js, schema

I have a problem with formatting Schema.org with Next and React, I get a very random error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token ':'` whenever I put the line `"@context" : "https://schema.org"`, however that error goes away if I remove that line, I also checked and remove the `@` character and everything runs perfectly, now my problem is Schema.org requires that `@context` property but it seems to clash with Next, how do I work around this?

```
import Head from "next/head";

function ViewPost({ post, episodeCount, name }) {

    const episodeKeys = Object.keys(post.episodes);

    return <>
        <Head>
            <script dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{
                __html: JSON.stringify({
                    "@context": "https://schema.org",
                    type: "Movie",
                    abstract: post.synopsis,
                    contentRating: "Mature",
                    genre: "anime",
                    inLanguage: "en",
                    keywords: `${post.tags.join(",")}`,
                    producer: {
                        "@type": "Organization",
                        name: post.studio
                    },
                    name: post.title,
                    text: post.summary,
                    thumbnailUrl: post.thumbnailImage.filePath
                })
            }} />
        </Head>
...
```

Answer (score 0):

Alright I fixed it, turns out I needed to add `type="application/ld+json"` to the script tag.